# Trying to link phoenix and MySQl compile.gettext error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, apache-phoenix

Look, It's beesn two weeks and i found nothing on the subject so you guys are my only hope on this.

I started a web project on Erlang VM which is a phoenix Based application. and i've been trying for ages to link the MySql Database i built to the app.

I followed the guide provided on the site...
http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/using-mysql

But when i arrive at the end of the guide, we have to initiate commands which i did. but when i do i get this strange error:
** (Mix) the task "compile.gettext" could not be found. did you mean "compile.leex"

I've tried looking everywhere and no answer. One forum i found told me to install Erlang-parsetool but to no success because it is already installed.

so i'm really in need of help right now. I'm not a setup guy and i've been setting this up for way to long. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Trying

`sudo apt-get install erlang-dev` fixed my problem.

And make sure you run,

```
sudo apt-get install erlang-parsetools
sudo apt-get install erlang-dev
```

Read the [issue #93](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gettext/issues/93)